# Why does Typescript allowed incorrect plain object return for Interface definition

Tags: typescript

**UPDATE:**

The 'why' is answered by another qution.

The 'how to fix' is now this new question:

[How can I make Typescript check that a return type is exactly matching a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534538/how-can-i-make-typescript-check-that-a-return-type-is-exactly-matching-a-structu)

---

Original:

Im missing error statement because Typescript isn't telling me that I have added incorrect data.

Why are Typescript allowing this?

Is this a bug or what is the reasoning for this?

> See codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k3ud7

```
interface ITester {
  string1: string;
}

type TestType<S = any> = (item: S) => S | undefined;

const Foo: TestType<ITester> = input => {
  return {
    ...input,
    foo: 42 // <-- This should not be allowed !
  };
};
```

More examples where Typescript does ensure that extra properties are not added:

```
const t1: ITester = {
  string1: "Hi",
  foo: 42 // <-- Typescript dont allow this
};
const Foo3: TestType<ITester> = input => {
  const returnVal: ITester = {
    ...input,
    foo: 42 // <-- Typescript dont allow this!
  };
  return returnVal;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) says:

> One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type checking focuses on the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or “structural subtyping”. In TypeScript, interfaces fill the role of naming these types, and are a powerful way of defining contracts within your code as well as contracts with code outside of your project.

An interface, in most languages that support the concept, is a set of properties. Any object that implements the interface must provide them but it is not forced to limit its properties to those defined by that interface. In fact, an object may implement any number of interfaces.
Even more, there is no need to declare when a class implements an interface. One can but they do not need to. TypeScript doesn't care about it. If an object provides all the properties defined as required by an interface then that object is compatible with the interface.

Or, using the [words of the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#our-first-interface):

> It’s worth pointing out that the type checker does not require that these properties come in any sort of order, only that the properties the interface requires are present and have the required type.

The declaration of your function says it returns an object that implements the interface `S`.
Any object that contains a string property named `string1` is compatible with the interface `S` and can be successfully returned by the function.

Comment: I can see that I should have added more examples from the Sandbox test. I have now updated the question. When I declare a new constant of an interface the check is done, but it isn't for the return type of the function. I also updated the actual question, because I really need to be able to make Typescript test my return type. Sorry for not being precise.